# Combinatorics. 4 white balls (with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4) and 2 black balls (with number 1, 2)

Tags: combinatorics

There are 4 white balls (with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 written on them)
and 2 black balls (with numbers 1, 2 written on them). How many ways there are
choose 3 balls, and they had different numbers.

I do not know where to start the solution. Give me a little hint.

Answer (score 2):

I would divide into cases depending on how many black balls I pick:

- No black balls. How many ways can this be done?
- One black ball. How many ways can this be done?
- Two black balls. How many ways can this be done?

Then add up the totals from each of the three points above, and you have your answer.

Comment: thanks, i solved it =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to split this up into cases:

$2$ Black and $1$ White: There are only $2$ ways this could happen. $B_1B_2W_3$ and $B_1B_2W_4$

$1$ Black and $2$ White: There are $2\times 3=6$ ways this could happen. The $2$ is there because the black ball could be either $1$ or $2$ and whatever number the black ball is, you have $3$ choices for white.

$0$ black and $3$ White: This is just ${4\choose 3}=4$

Add them all up to give $2+6+4=12.$